# Embedded Redis for Spring Boot

Tags: java, redis, spring-boot

I run my Integration Test cases with Spring Boot with the help of my local Redis server on my machine.

But I want an embedded Redis server which is not dependent on any server and can run on any environment, like the H2 in-memory database. How can I do it?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("server.port:0")
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class) 
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public class MasterIntegrationTest {

}
```

Comment: did you check https://github.com/kstyrc/embedded-redis

Comment: Yes i checked but i am a little bit confused i mean i just want to know do i have to create @Bean RedisServer getserver(){} to inject it ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use an embedded Redis like https://github.com/kstyrc/embedded-redis

1. Add the dependency to your pom.xml
2. Adjust the properties for your integration test to point to your embedded redis, for example :

   ```
   spring:
     redis:
       host: localhost
       port: 6379
   ```
3. Instanciate the embedded redis server in a  component that is defined in your tests only :

   ```
   @Component
   public class EmbededRedis {

       @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
       private int redisPort;

       private RedisServer redisServer;

       @PostConstruct
       public void startRedis() throws IOException {
           redisServer = new RedisServer(redisPort);
           redisServer.start();
       }

       @PreDestroy
       public void stopRedis() {
           redisServer.stop();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: is there any way to set password for the embedded server ?

Comment: probably, check out the doc of the github project, it seems to be pretty configurable

Comment: The project doesn't seem to be actively maintained anymore. Last release was close to two years ago.

Comment: https://github.com/ozimov/embedded-redis is the successor of https://github.com/kstyrc/embedded-redis, I added an extra answer using ozimov/embedded-redis.

Comment: I'm using the successor - and I know this is an old post, but looks like the lack of logging with this make it hard to use in a CICD context - atm tests work on local windows machine - but when committed to build machine they fail - and no way to write logs. Any idea? its a unix build machine.

Comment: maybe something about the ports being already in use on the build machine ?

Comment: Not working with Redisson client, https://github.com/kstyrc/embedded-redis/issues/94

Comment: you can my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456421/reliable-libraries-out-there-for-spring-boot-redis-integration-tests/51282408#51282408

Comment: How to stop the embedded redis server? I had not added stop method, it was just start

Comment: I have seen in a number of places, that embedded Redis is only recommended for testing. Why is this?

Comment: Found Netflix version of embedded-redis, with newer redis support: https://bintray.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/embedded-redis

Comment: @Renjith Regarding the password, I was able to successfully set it using `.setting("requirepass " + redisPassword)`.  This was with the ozimov version

Answer (score 28):

edit : I would now strongly suggest to go the testcontainers route as explained in @magiccrafter [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50645865/7059), I am also using it for my tests now.

---

You can use [ozimov/embedded-redis](https://github.com/ozimov/embedded-redis) as a Maven(-test)-dependency (this is the successor of [kstyrc/embedded-redis](https://github.com/kstyrc/embedded-redis)).

1. Add the dependency to your pom.xml

   ```
    <dependencies>
      ...
      <dependency>
        <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
        <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   ```
2. Adjust your application properties for your integration test

   ```
    spring.redis.host=localhost
    spring.redis.port=6379
   ```
3. Use the embedded redis server in a [test configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config)

   ```
    @TestConfiguration
    public static class EmbededRedisTestConfiguration {

      private final redis.embedded.RedisServer redisServer;

      public EmbededRedisTestConfiguration(@Value("${spring.redis.port}") final int redisPort) throws IOException {
        this.redisServer = new redis.embedded.RedisServer(redisPort);
      }

      @PostConstruct
      public void startRedis() {
        this.redisServer.start();
      }

      @PreDestroy
      public void stopRedis() {
        this.redisServer.stop();
      }
    }
   ```

Comment: This also is not maintained!! (

Comment: It is only wise to move away from embedded-redis as it is not maintained. Another response suggesting to use testcontainers should now be the accepted solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/50645865/12221963

Comment: [codemonstur/embedded-redis](https://github.com/codemonstur/embedded-redis), [ponfee/embedded-redis](https://github.com/ponfee/embedded-redis), [simbahebinbo/embedded-redis](https://github.com/simbahebinbo/embedded-redis) and [signalapp/embedded-redis](https://github.com/signalapp/embedded-redis) are somewhat recently updated forks of embedded-redis. There are some differences between them, e.g. only the first two support Windows.

Answer (score 12):

Another neat way is to use the [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org) library which can run any type of application that can in a Docker container and Redis is no exception. What I like best is that it is lightly coupled with the Spring Test ecosystem.

maven's dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
    <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

simple integration test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {"management.port=0"})
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = AbstractIntegrationTest.Initializer.class)
@DirtiesContext
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {

    private static int REDIS_PORT = 6379;

    @ClassRule
    public static GenericContainer redis = new GenericContainer("redis:5-alpine").withExposedPorts(REDIS_PORT);

    public static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {
            // Spring Boot 1.5.x
            TestPropertySourceUtils.addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment(ctx,
                "spring.redis.host=" + redis.getContainerIpAddress(),
                "spring.redis.port=" + redis.getMappedPort(REDIS_PORT));

            // Spring Boot 2.x.
            TestPropertyValues.of(
                "spring.redis.host:" + redis.getContainerIpAddress(),
                "spring.redis.port:" + redis.getMappedPort(REDIS_PORT))
                .applyTo(ctx);
        }
    }
}
```

Since Spring Framework 5.2.5 (Spring Boot 2.3.x) you can use the powerful `DynamicPropertySource` annotation.
Here is an example:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractIT {

    static GenericContainer redisContainer = new GenericContainer("redis:5-alpine").withExposedPorts(6379);

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void properties(DynamicPropertyRegistry r) throws IOException {
        r.add("spring.redis.host", redisContainer::getContainerIpAddress);
        r.add("spring.redis.port", redisContainer::getFirstMappedPort);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there way to know redis container image name based on the test container library we are using?

Answer (score 1):

you can see this repository: https://github.com/caryyu/spring-embedded-redis-server , fully integrated with Spring and Spring Boot

## maven dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.github.caryyu</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-embedded-redis-server</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

## spring boot annotation

```
@Bean
public RedisServerConfiguration redisServerConfiguration() {
return new RedisServerConfiguration();
}
```

## usage of application.yml

```
spring:
    redis:
        port: 6379
        embedded: true
```

Comment: Repository documentation is in Chinese, if you find an English version please post the link.

Comment: this project is basically a wrapper of the one mentioned in the accepted answer. Pointless

Answer (score 1):

If your are using spring and reactive to [access data with redis reactively](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-data-reactive-redis/).
Meaning you're having a `ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory` (with a `RedisConnectionFactory` bean) and a `LettuceConnectionFactory` then you may want to follow this approach to set an embedded redis for multiple test classes.

First add the [playtika embedded redis](https://github.com/Playtika/testcontainers-spring-boot/blob/develop/embedded-redis/README.adoc) to your dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile("com.playtika.testcontainers:embedded-redis:2.0.9")
}
```

Then set the redis host and port as the `embedded.redis` one in your application.yml (that are generated by the embedded redis as env variable on creation).

```yaml
spring:
  redis:
    host: \${embedded.redis.host:localhost}
    port: \${embedded.redis.port:6739}
```

In a `bootstrap-redisnoauth.properties` file, set the env variable `embedded.redis.requirepass=false` so that it does not require password.

Then in your test use the active profile:

```java
@ActiveProfiles("redisnoauth")
```

And make sure to have this `@TestConfiguration` in your test class as well so that will connect you to the redis spawned on a randomly generated port.

```java
@Category(IntegrationTest.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("redisnoauth")
public class RedisCacheTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class RedisTestConfiguration {
    
        @Bean
        public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(@Value("${spring.redis.host}") String host,
                                                             @Value("${spring.redis.port}") int port) {
            return new LettuceConnectionFactory(host, port);
        }
    
        @Bean
        public RedisOperations<String, String> stringKeyAndStringValueRedisOperations(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
            RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
            redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
            redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer(UTF_8));
            redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer(UTF_8));
            return redisTemplate;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
      // your test
    }

}
```

And it should work smoothly.