# Reliable libraries out there for Spring boot redis integration tests

Tags: spring-boot, redis, integration-testing

This is more of a question for a tool - googling around I haven't really had much luck.

So basically I have a standard spring boot app - and I have a unit test redis cache configuration. What I am looking to do is run the app context autowire some spring configs and test against a embedded redis cache if possible.

Closest I have come is this https://github.com/kstyrc/embedded-redis.

Problem with that is the lack of robust logging is making it difficult to run - its working locally, but when I push it up, Unix server build machine, its failing and no idea why.

If anyone has any idea of how to run integration tests this way - it would be great.

thanks,

Stefan

Comment: The JAR that you downloaded only contains the Windows EXE. There are instructions in ReadMe on the project’s home page explaining how to use other OS executables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using [embedded-redis](https://github.com/ozimov/embedded-redis) for my integration testing with redisson java client.
Here is my dependency

```
compile group: 'org.redisson', name: 'redisson', version: '3.6.5'
testCompile group: 'it.ozimov', name: 'embedded-redis', version: '0.7.2'
```

Start embedded redis server before class and stop it in after class.

**Redis property:**

```
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379
```

**Sample** integration test.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.redisson.api.RMap;
import org.redisson.api.RMapCache;
import org.redisson.api.RedissonClient;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;


import redis.embedded.RedisServer;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class RedisTest {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisTest.class);

    private static RedisServer REDISSERVER = new RedisServer(6379);

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private RedissonClient redissonClient;

    @BeforeClass
    public static final void before() {
        REDISSERVER.start();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static  final void after() { 
        REDISSERVER.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void testRedis() throws InterruptedException {
        //map
        RMap<String, String> map = redissonClient.getMap("user");
        map.put("name", "Redis Server");
        Assert.assertTrue(map.get("name").equals("Redis Server"));

        //mapcache
        RMapCache<String, String> mapCache = redissonClient.getMapCache("tempUser");
        mapCache.put("name", "Redis Server", 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Assert.assertTrue(mapCache.get("name").equals("Redis Server"));
        Thread.sleep(7000); //wait for 7 sec.
        Assert.assertTrue(mapCache.get("name") == null);
    }
}
```

Comment: ozimov/embedded-redis is not maintained anymore. [codemonstur/embedded-redis](https://github.com/codemonstur/embedded-redis), [ponfee/embedded-redis](https://github.com/ponfee/embedded-redis), [simbahebinbo/embedded-redis](https://github.com/simbahebinbo/embedded-redis) and [signalapp/embedded-redis](https://github.com/signalapp/embedded-redis) are somewhat recently updated forks of embedded-redis. There are some differences between them, e.g. only the first two support Windows.

Comment: you can use : https://github.com/redis-developer/testcontainers-redis